# Rendering react components using json schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to render React component dynamically using JSON. My folder structure is like this:

```
components
   Foo.jsx
   Bar.jsx
   index.js
App.jsx
```

In `index.js`, I am exporting all the components as strings so that I can use them to render in `App.jsx`. It looks like this:

```
import Foo from './Foo'
import Bar from './Bar'

export default {
  'FOO': Foo,
  'BAR': Bar
}
```

My `App.jsx` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ComponentsMap from './components'

const json = {'type': 'BAR', props: {}} 
const App = () => {
   const ComponentToRender = ComponentsMap[json.type]
   return (
      <ComponentToRender {...json.props} />
   )
}
```

In my approach, every time I add a new component I have to export it in `index.js` as well. Is there any other alternative way to do it?

Comment: Whenever you create a new component, you will need to export it(one way or the other). The component will need to explicitly be exported, else `webpack`(or any other bundler) will not know how to resolve its part.

Answer (score 1):

Try wildcard plugin of babel. It will import all files exists in a directory. Then you don't need index.jsx, import all components via * inside App.jsx.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-wildcard

Hope this can help you.